# php how can i include internal pages by url?

Tags: php, html, include

for example my website is "myweb.com". how can i do opration  like following.

```
include(http://myweb.com/file);
```

this is an internal URL.

for example  i want to include

```
http://myweb.com/process.php?action=update
```

this is not a file

```
 "?action=update"
```

thus how can i do this operation?

Comment: Your question sounds an awful lot like this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: @DanyCaissy Obviously he copy and pasted it. In the first version of the question there was also the paste of "12 votes 1 favorite".

Answer (score 0):

To include pages with PHP, simply put the following code in `a.html`, where you would like the code to appear:

```
<?php
    include "b.html";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include an HTML document into another HTML document.

You can do that using PHP but the file that includes the other *must* be a PHP document. In your example `a` includes `b` therefore `a` is `a.php` while `b` can stay `b.html`.

Then inside `a.php` you can write:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('b.html'); ?>
```

and the content of `b.html` will be included into `a.php`.

Comment: You *can* include an HTML document inside a PHP document, but assuming the HTML document is valid, you'd get invalid code. For example, an HTML file would have its own HTML, head, and body tags, which shouldn't be included inside another HTML document's body.

Comment: @Mike, "You can include an HTML document inside a PHP document". Yes, I said you *can't* include an HTML document inside another HTML document.

Comment: It is possible Jeffrey, you can do something like this : <iframe src="page.html"></iframe>

Comment: @DanyCaissy, an `iframe` isn't exactly like including an HTML page. `iframe`s have different headers.

Comment: I know, but it's not impossible to include HTML in another HTML document. Maybe you can just reword it better and use the world "shouldn't" instead of "can't".